# Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'price' at row 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update price field which type is decimal (8,2). It works fine.. But when I lookup the server logs I see that sometimes it throws above error.

```
update `services` set `price` = 52,50 where `id` = 696
```

What may causes this error ?

Comment: `52,50` is not a valid numeric value. This query should raise a syntax/parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is (dot instead comma in decimal number):

```
update `services` set `price` = 52.50 where `id` = 696;
```